# Validate a List of dto (validation annotations put on the dto aren't working)

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, validation, post

I have a DTO class with validation annotations & in a Post API request, I have to take a List of this DTO, but the validations that I have added in the DTO aren't working.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public MyTinyDto test(@Valid @RequestBody List<MyTinyDto> myDtos) {
    return myDtos.get(0);
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyTinyDto {
    @Min(value = 10,
            message = "Min value of Integer is ten")
    Integer x;
}
```

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/843bl.png)

Comment: Use `@Valid @RequestBody List<@Valid MyTineDto>` if that doesn't work use a wrapper object that has `@Valid` on the collection.

Comment: Thank you for your help, `@Valid @RequestBody List<@Valid MyTineDto>` did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Validated` to class rest controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Validated
public class Test{

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public MyTinyDto test(@Valid @RequestBody List<MyTinyDto> myDtos) {
        return myDtos.get(0);

}
```

Comment: Great! :) So vote the answer and close ticket :)

Comment: That serves a whole different purpose then `@Valid` on the web handliung method, it is even handled differently!.

Comment: Sure but, documentation said: 

`What is @validated in Spring boot?
@Validated annotation is a class-level annotation that we can use to tell Spring to validate parameters that are passed into a method of the annotated class. and. @Valid annotation on method parameters and fields to tell Spring that we want a method parameter or field to be validated` So you can validate any type of bean with mixing `@Valid` for fields of object